# Error Code: 1235. This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'COUNT(DISTINCT) aggregate as window function'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions

I have the following table on a MariaDB:

```
date              name

2018-01-02        John
2018-01-03        Mary
2018-01-05        Peter
2018-01-06        John
2018-01-07        Ann
2018-01-08        Ann
2018-01-09        John
2018-01-10        Peter
```

And I want to compute the cumulated_name_count on each day. i.e. I am expecting my results like:

```
date        cumulated_name_count

2018-01-02        1
2018-01-03        2
2018-01-04        2
2018-01-05        3
2018-01-06        3
2018-01-07        4
2018-01-08        4
2018-01-09        4
2018-01-10        4
```

To achieve this, I am using the following code with window function:

```
select date, 
  count(distinct name) over (order by time rows unbounded preceding) 
  as cumulated_name_count from myDB.myTable
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'COUNT(DISTINCT) aggregate as window function'
```

Is there a way to avoid such error and get the cumulated count over a window function? Thanks!

Comment: Also needed is a `RIGHT JOIN` to a list of dates, else `2018-01-04` won't show up in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with nested window functions:

```
select date, 
       sum( seqnum = 1 ) over (order by time rows unbounded preceding)
              as cumulated_name_count
    from (select  t.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by name order by time)
                        as seqnum
              from myDB.myTable t
         ) t2;
```

The subquery enumerates each `name` value by time.  The outer query then counts the number of "1" up to each record.

Comment: Hi, I got this error: Error Code: 4017. Window frame is not allowed with 'row_number' ... Is this the problem due to MariaDB version? How could I go around it? Thanks!

Comment: Is "rows unbounded preceding" actually needed in (partition by name order by time rows unbounded preceding)?

Comment: @Edamame . . . It is not needed.  I just left it in when I copied code.